# Problem with connecting existing user table with asp.net user table in Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, entity

I want to connect aspnetusers table with existing workoutuser table, my workoutuser table store own id which is needed/connected to other tables in database, I changed in controller and other classes IdentityUser to WorkoutUser and in WorkoutUser im inheriting from IdentityUser, but then that error appears [error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Yt6o.png), where is the problem? pls help

```
public class WorkoutUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int WorkoutUserID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50,MinimumLength =2 )]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string City { get; set; }


    public ICollection<UserExercise> UserExercises { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserTraining> UserTrainings { get; set; }
    public ICollection<LogTraining> LogTrainings { get;set; }
}
```

My controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<WorkoutUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<WorkoutUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<WorkoutUser> userManager, SignInManager<WorkoutUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }



    [HttpGet("register")]
    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {   //UserName = model.Email.Split("@")[0]
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {


            var user = new WorkoutUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded) {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return RedirectToAction("index", "trainings");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }

        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Table workoutuser structure

```
    [WorkoutUserID] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [LastName]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [City]          NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkoutUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([WorkoutUserID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Please post your table structure - the error is stating that the table columns cannot be found.

Comment: okay, I have added

Comment: Look at the error message - it's saying it can't find a column (or columns??) called 'Discriminator' !!

Comment: You are using Asp.Net Mvc or asp.net core?

Comment: Asp.net core, i was searching for a solution but its not working,. i just want to link aspnetuser with my other tables in database by table workoutuser